# PHP Redirection Error - not sure of the issue (new to PHP)

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I'm pretty new to PHP - I'm using a script that works great apart from one page. It is a Rare Values site for items. It can be viewed at ClassicHabbox.com/values

The main issue is on the admin side of things. You can add a value to the site no problem, you just can't edit the value. If I wanted to edit value 214 for example, it will try and take me to the following address http://classichabbox.com/values/admin/editvalue.214 - this comes up as a 404 error. Maybe it's an issue with the PHP, or even HTACCESS?

I have listed below the editvalue.php of /admin and my HTACCESS file.

I have also created an account for you to use, to see what I mean.

http://classichabbox.com/values/admin/login

Username: Stack
Password: Overflow

**editvalue.php**

```
<?php

    define('BoonValues', true);
    require_once('../global.php');

    if(!$core->loggedIn())
    {
        header('Location: '. $config['Site']['Link'] .'/admin/login');
        exit;
    }

    if(!$admin->hasPermission('editvalue', $_SESSION['admin']['username']))
    {
        header('Location: '. $config['Site']['Link'] .'/admin/permissions');
        exit;
    }

    if(isset($_POST['value']))
    {
        header('Location: '. $config['Site']['Link'] .'/admin/editvalue.'. $_POST['value']);
        exit;
    }

    if(isset($_GET['value']))
    {
        if(is_numeric($_GET['value']))
        {
            $pdo->query('SELECT `id`, `name`, `image`, `value_now`, `category`, `hidden` FROM `values_list` WHERE `id` = :rareId');
            $pdo->bind(':rareId', $_GET['value']);

            $aboutRare = $pdo->single();

            if(!$aboutRare)
            {
                $message = 'The selected rare does not exist.';
                $messageType = 'alert-danger';
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $message = 'Invalid rare selected.';
            $messageType = 'alert-danger';
        }
    }

    if(isset($_POST['rareName'], $_POST['rareImage'], $_POST['rareCategory'], $_POST['rareValue'], $_POST['valueChoice'], $_POST['hidden']))
    {
        $categories = array('HC', 'normal', 'super');

        if(is_numeric($_GET['value']))
        {
            $pdo->query('SELECT `id`, `name`, `image`, `value_now`, `category`, `hidden` FROM `values_list` WHERE `id` = :rareId');
            $pdo->bind(':rareId', $_GET['value']);

            $rareDetail = $pdo->single();

            if($rareDetail)
            {
                if(in_array($_POST['rareCategory'], $categories))
                {
                    $hidden = ($_POST['ltd'] == 'Not Hidden' ? '0' : '1');
                    $newName = ($admin->hasPermission('editvalue_name', $_SESSION['admin']['username']) ? $_POST['rareName'] : $rareDetail['name']);
                    $newImage = ($admin->hasPermission('editvalue_image', $_SESSION['admin']['username']) ? $_POST['rareImage'] : $rareDetail['image']);
                    $newCategory = ($admin->hasPermission('editvalue_category', $_SESSION['admin']['username']) ? $_POST['rareCategory'] : $rareDetail['category']);
                    $newHidden = ($admin->hasPermission('editvalue_hidden', $_SESSION['admin']['username']) ? $hidden : $rareDetail['ltd']);

                    if($admin->hasPermission('editvalue_value', $_SESSION['admin']['username']))
                    {
                        if($_POST['valueChoice'] == 'thrones')
                        {
                            $newValue = throneValue * $_POST['rareValue'];
                        }
                        else if($_POST['valueChoice'] == 'pbs')
                        {
                            $newValue = $_POST['rareValue'] * 5000;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $newValue = $_POST['rareValue'];
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $newValue = $rareDetail['value_now'];
                    }

                    if($rareDetail['value_now'] > $newValue)
                    {
                        $change = $rareDetail['value_now'] - $newValue;
                        $way = 'down';
                        $silent = '0';
                    }
                    else if($rareDetail['value_now'] < $newValue)
                    {
                        $change = $newValue - $rareDetail['value_now'];
                        $way = 'up';
                        $silent = '0';
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $change = '0';
                        $way = 'neutral';
                        $silent = '1';
                    }

                    $admin->recordEvent('Edit Value', 'Changed value of ID '. $rareDetail['id'] .' from '. $rareDetail['value_now'] .' to '. $newValue .'.');

                    $pdo->query('INSERT INTO `values_history` (`rareid`, `name`, `value`, `change`, `direction`, `silent`, `timestamp`, `changedby`) VALUES (:rareId, :name, :value, :change, :direction, :silent, :timestamp, :username)');
                    $pdo->bind(':rareId', $_GET['value']);
                    $pdo->bind(':name', $newName);
                    $pdo->bind(':value', $newValue);
                    $pdo->bind(':change', $change);
                    $pdo->bind(':direction', $way);
                    $pdo->bind(':silent', $silent);
                    $pdo->bind(':timestamp', time());
                    $pdo->bind(':username', $_SESSION['admin']['username']);
                    $pdo->execute();

                    $pdo->query('UPDATE `values_list` SET `name` = :name, `image` = :image, `value_now` = :value, `category` = :category, `hidden` = :hidden WHERE `id` = :rareId');
                    $pdo->bind(':rareId', $_GET['value']);
                    $pdo->bind(':name', $newName);
                    $pdo->bind(':image', $newImage);
                    $pdo->bind(':value', $newValue);
                    $pdo->bind(':category', $newCategory);
                    $pdo->bind(':hidden', $newHidden);
                    $pdo->execute();

                    $message = 'Rare updated and cache cleared.';
                    $messageType = 'alert-success';

                    $core->destroyCache();
                }
                else
                {
                    $message = 'Invalid category selected.';
                    $messageType = 'alert-danger';
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $message = 'The selected rare does not exist.';
                $messageType = 'alert-danger';
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $message = 'Invalid rare selected.';
            $messageType = 'alert-danger';
        }
    }

    $selectedPage = '2-1';

?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>BoonValues - Edit Value</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $config['Site']['Link']; ?>/resources/styles/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $config['Site']['Link']; ?>/resources/styles/navbar.css">

        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script src="<?php echo $config['Site']['Link']; ?>/resources/scripts/html5shiv.js"></script>
            <script src="<?php echo $config['Site']['Link']; ?>/resources/scripts/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
    </head>

    <body>
        <?php include_once('navbar.php'); ?>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="page-header"><h2><?php if(isset($_GET['value'])){ ?><a href="<?php echo $config['Site']['Link']; ?>/admin/editvalue">&laquo;</a> <?php } ?>Edit Value</h2></div>

            <?php

                if(isset($message, $messageType))
                {
                    echo '<div class="alert '. $messageType .'">'. $message .'</div>';
                }

                if(!isset($_GET['value']))
                {

                    if(!$admin->hasPermission('editvalue_hidden', $_SESSION['admin']['username']))
                    {
                        $pdo->query('SELECT `id`, `name`, `category`, `hidden` FROM `values_list` WHERE `hidden` = :hidden');
                        $pdo->bind(':hidden', '0');
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $pdo->query('SELECT `id`, `name`, `category` FROM `values_list`');
                    }

                    $list = $pdo->resultSet();

            ?>
                <form method="post" class="form-inline" role="form">
                    <select class="form-control input-sm" id="rareValue" name="value" style="width: 50%;">
                        <option value="0">Select A Rare</option>
                        <option value="0"></option>
                        <optgroup label="HC Rares">
                        <?php

                            foreach($list as $rare)
                            {
                                if($rare['category'] == 'HC')
                                {

                        ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $rare['id']; ?>"><?php echo $rare['name']; ?></option>
                        <?php

                                }
                            }

                        ?>
                        </optgroup>
                        <optgroup label="Normal Rares">
                        <?php

                            foreach($list as $rare)
                            {
                                if($rare['category'] == 'normal')
                                {

                        ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $rare['id']; ?>"><?php echo $rare['name']; ?></option>
                        <?php

                                }
                            }

                        ?>
                        </optgroup>
                        <optgroup label="Super Rares">
                        <?php

                            foreach($list as $rare)
                            {
                                if($rare['category'] == 'super')
                                {

                        ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $rare['id']; ?>"><?php echo $rare['name']; ?></option>
                        <?php

                                }
                            }

                        ?>
                        </optgroup>
                    </select>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="submit">Edit</button>
                </form>
            <?php } else { ?>
                <form method="post" role="form" style="width: 50%;">
                    <input type="hidden" name="rareid" value="<?php echo $_GET['value']; ?>">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="rareName">Name:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="rareName" name="rareName" placeholder="Name" value="<?php echo $aboutRare['name']; ?>" <?php if(!$admin->hasPermission('editvalue_name', $_SESSION['admin']['username'])){ echo 'readonly'; } ?>>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group" style="<?php if(!$admin->hasPermission('editvalue_image', $_SESSION['admin']['username'])){ echo 'display: none;'; } ?>">
                        <label for="rareImage">Image:</label>
                        <select class="form-control" id="rareImage" name="rareImage">
                        <?php
                        $arr=array();
                        if($open = opendir(ROOT .'/resources/images/small_furni')) {
                            while(false != ($file = readdir($open))) {
                                if($file == '.' || $file == '..') {
                                    continue;
                                }
                                $files[]=$file;
                            }
                        }
                        sort($files);
                        foreach($files as $file) echo '<option value="'. $file .'" '. ((isset($rareimage) && $rareimage == $file) ? 'selected' : '') .'>'. $file .'</option>';
                        ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group" style="<?php if(!$admin->hasPermission('editvalue_category', $_SESSION['admin']['username'])){ echo 'display: none;'; } ?>">
                        <label for="rareCategory">Category:</label>
                        <select class="form-control" id="rareCategory" name="rareCategory">
                            <option value="HC" <?php if($aboutRare['category'] == 'HC'){ echo 'selected'; } ?>>HC Rare</option>
                            <option value="normal" <?php if($aboutRare['category'] == 'normal'){ echo 'selected'; } ?>>Normal Rare</option>
                            <option value="super" <?php if($aboutRare['category'] == 'super'){ echo 'selected'; } ?>>Super Rare</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group" style="<?php if(!$admin->hasPermission('editvalue_value', $_SESSION['admin']['username'])){ echo 'display: none;'; } ?>">
                        <label for="rareValue">Value:</label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="rareValue" name="rareValue" placeholder="Value" value="<?php echo $aboutRare['value_now']; ?>">
                            <div class="input-group-btn">
                                <input type="hidden" name="valueChoice" value="credits" id="valueChoice">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" tabindex="-1" id="valueSelector" value="1" style="margin-right: -1px;">Credits</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" tabindex="-1">
                                    <span class="caret"></span>
                                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
                                </button>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right" role="menu">
                                    <li id="changeType4" class="active"><a id="changeType1" style="cursor: pointer;">Credits</a></li>
                                    <li id="changeType5"><a id="changeType2" style="cursor: pointer;">Thrones</a></li>
                                    <li id="changeType6"><a id="changeType3" style="cursor: pointer;">Platinum Bars</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="radio-inline" style="<?php if(!$admin->hasPermission('editvalue_hidden', $_SESSION['admin']['username'])){ echo 'display: none;'; } ?>">
                            <input type="radio" name="hidden" id="hidden1" value="Hidden" <?php if($aboutRare['hidden'] == '1'){ echo 'checked'; } ?>> Hidden
                        </label>
                        <label class="radio-inline" style="<?php if(!$admin->hasPermission('editvalue_hidden', $_SESSION['admin']['username'])){ echo 'display: none;'; } ?>">
                            <input type="radio" name="hidden" id="hidden2" value="Not Hidden" <?php if($aboutRare['hidden'] == '0'){ echo 'checked'; } ?>> Not Hidden
                        </label>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" style="float: right;">Save</button>
                        <?php if($admin->hasPermission('deletevalue', $_SESSION['admin']['username'])){ ?>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" name="deleteRare" style="float: right; margin-right: 5px;">Delete Rare</button>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </div>
                </form>
            <?php } ?>
        </div>

        <script src="<?php echo $config['Site']['Link']; ?>/resources/scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="<?php echo $config['Site']['Link']; ?>/resources/scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="<?php echo $config['Site']['Link']; ?>/resources/scripts/values.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

.htaccess file - in /values directory

```
# Run Php without filename extension
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

# Return 404 if original request is .php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} "^[^ ]* .*?\.php[? ].*$"
RewriteRule .* - [L,R=404]
```

PHP Version 5.4

Comment: Wouldn't `editValue/214` make more sense? Using a `.` has the web server looking for a file with the value as file ending.

Comment: You are doing a redirect in order to copy the key 'value' from $_POST to $_GET?

Comment: @ChrisSatchell Hi, I changed it to a slash, now gives 500 internal server error

Comment: Your current rewriting is not affecting this requested URL at all - because all you are doing, is check if what was requested with the suffix `.php` added exists as a physical file, and if so, redirect to that file internally. Now, what you requested was `editvalue.214` (or `editvalue/214`) - question: Does a file named `editvalue.214.php` (or `editvalue/214.php`) actually physically exist …? Well there’s your answer then.

Comment: How are you expecting `/values/admin/editvalue.214` to be routed? How are you expecting the value `214` be be passed to your `editvalue.php` script? It looks like your script is expecting a `value` URL parameter?